# I need help coinbase api pushing jquery val() into php price

Tags: php, jquery, bitcoin

im having a bit of a problem. with this coinbase api.. as, i am new to jquery.

i have a small script that allows users to insert a price, and it calculates the total instantly... I am wanting the jquery total, to be put into a php array. so, users can click on the payment button of bitcoin, and have their total that they just entered.

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#product').on('keyup change', function(){
        $('#ssfee').text($('#product').val() * 1.10);
    });
});
```

the php code:

```
echo $coinbase->createButton("Alpaca Socks", "100.00", "USD")->embedHtml;
```

**what i want is:**

```
echo $coinbase->createButton("Alpaca Socks", "$('#ssfee')", "USD")->embedHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not a javascript expert myself, but why not set the price as a variable and then paste the variable in the php code? So basically create something like `var ssfee = "$100.00"` and then simply paste that variable in the place of `#ssfee` Hope this helps.